# Route loads notFound briefly first

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a iron route that searches for a collection item based on the url param. If it finds it, it returns the item as a data context, otherwise it renders a `notFound` template. The code looks like this:

```
this.route('profileView', {
        path: list_path + '/profiles/:_id',
        fastRender: true,
        waitOn: function() {
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                return [Meteor.subscribe('singleProfile', this.params._id, Session.get("currentListId"))];
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            var profile = Profiles.findOne({
                _id: this.params._id
            });
            if (!profile) {
                this.render("notFound");
            } else
                return profile;
        }
    });
```

The problem is the `notFound` template gets loaded briefly prior to profile getting returned, although I thought the `waitOn` function would have handled that. What's the correct pattern to have the desired result using iron router? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check for this.ready() in data. Updated code

```
this.route('profileView', {
        path: list_path + '/profiles/:_id',
        fastRender: true,
        waitOn: function() {
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                return [Meteor.subscribe('singleProfile', this.params._id, Session.get("currentListId"))];
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            if(this.ready()){
                var profile = Profiles.findOne({
                    _id: this.params._id
                });
                if (!profile) {
                    this.render("notFound");
                } else
                    return profile;
            }
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you forgot to configure the `loading` and `dataNotFound` hooks?

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound');
```

If you want to understand what is actually going on here, please [look here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/client/hooks.js).